# some error come from plyer on android and python3crystax

Tags: android, python, python-3.x

i use python3crystax to build plyer apk but when i run apk on android it show error message "Accessing org.renpy.android.PythonActivity is deprecated and will be removed in a future version." i try to use old version of python-for-android it get other error !

if i just change plyer init  Activity it can run but still can see any notify!

`File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
11-07 00:58:08.840 7082-7112/youer.com.school I/python:      from kivy.app import App
11-07 00:58:08.841 7082-7112/youer.com.school I/python:    File "/data/user/0/youer.com.school/files/app/crystax_python/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 319, in <module>
11-07 00:58:08.843 7082-7112/youer.com.school I/python:      from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
11-07 00:58:08.843 7082-7112/youer.com.school I/python:    File "/data/user/0/youer.com.school/files/app/crystax_python/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 26, in <module>
11-07 00:58:08.845 7082-7112/youer.com.school I/python:      from kivy.clock import Clock
11-07 00:58:08.845 7082-7112/youer.com.school I/python:    File "/data/user/0/youer.com.school/files/app/crystax_python/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 362, in <module>
11-07 00:58:08.847 7082-7112/youer.com.school I/python:      from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, \
11-07 00:58:08.848 7082-7112/youer.com.school I/python:  ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Py_NoneStruct" referenced by "/data/data/youer.com.school/files/app/crystax_python/site-packages/kivy/_clock.so"...`

Answer (score 0):

change `org.renpy.android.PythonActivity` to `org.kivy.android.PythonActivity`